# Variable importance in fixed-effects model

Tags: r, panel-data

I am trying to estimate the relative variable importance of my fixed effects regression model.

```
model1 <- plm (sales ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, 
              data = df, effect="individual",
              index = c("country", "month"),model= "within")
```

When I run code from the 'caret' package:

```
varImp(model1, scale = FALSE)
```

I get the following error message:

*Error in UseMethod("varImp") :
no applicable method for 'varImp' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"*

Any suggestions for other ways of estimating the relative importance of the variables in my fixed-effects model?

Comment: Have a look at the `fixest` package here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html#5_Additional_features (chapter 1.8)

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you for your comment. When I use the approach from fixest, i get fixed-effects coefficients for each of the countries. However, I am interested in how important each of the variables in my model are. E.g., how important is x2 for the model? 
Does this make sense?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Variable importance is not a concept commonly discussed in the context of mixed-effect models. Usually one would discuss effect sizes associated with standardised inputs. Variable importance (as in from typical ML procedures) would relate to comparing multiple models to estimate the importance of specific variables. This is generally not the adopted approach in mixed-effect modelling.

Comment: Thank you FKneip. I think the correct approach in my case was simply to standardize the inputs so that I could more easily speak to the relative importance of the input variables.